# NameError: name is not defined. Circular Importing

Tags: python, import

I am having difficulty with a circular import problem. I have 2 class files like so:

```
--/service
    service_module.py
    settings.py
```

service_module imports other various files used throughout the project and acts as a container for various functions throughout the project. I want to assert in my settings.py file that it is properly passed an instance of the service_module parent class. Removing the assert statement in settings.py fixes the issue and I am able to properly call methods in the service_module class. For code completion and error checking it makes my life easier to assert.

I have always struggled with understanding python imports but is this the right direction to handle my particular case?

service_module.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, Session, sessionmaker
from service.logger import logger
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound
from database.tables import *
from database.load_db import load_db
from service.settings import settings
from service.web_listener import web_listener
from service.character_manager import character_manager


class Service_Module(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Service_Module, self).__init__()
        load_database = load_db()
        self.sc_session: scoped_session = load_database.get_scoped_session()
        tb_scopes.make_default_scopes(service_module=self)
        self.logger = logger(service_module=self)
        self.settings = settings(service_module=self)
        self.characters = character_manager(service_module=self)
        self.callback_listener: web_listener = web_listener(service_module=self)
        self.callback_listener.start()
        assert isinstance(self.sc_session, scoped_session)
        assert isinstance(self.logger, logger)
        assert isinstance(self.settings, settings)
        assert isinstance(self.callback_listener, web_listener)
```

settings.py

```
from service.service_module import *


class settings(QObject):

    def __init__(self, service_module):
        super(settings, self).__init__()
        self.service = service_module
        assert isinstance(self.service, Service_Module) ##raises NameError: name 'Service_Module' is not defined
```

Edit: 
So changing to this solves my issue although I feel like it's kind of hacky and somehow incorrect.

```
from service.service_module import *
import service.service_module

    class settings(QObject):

        def __init__(self, service_module):
            super(settings, self).__init__()
            self.service = service_module
            assert isinstance(self.service, service.service_module.Service_Module)
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't look hacky to me; importing the module itself instead of directly importing objects from the module is a method I use myself when I find myself getting problems with circular imports. However, you may want to remove the line `from service.service_module import *` now unless there is still need for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delay the importing of one (or both) of the files, to break the circular import.  You can do this by moving the import statement from file-scope (where it is executed as soon as the module is imported) into the execution scope of a function or method, where is not executed until that method is called.  Ie)

```
class setting(QObject):
    def __init__(self, service_module):
        from service.service_module import Service_Module       # <-- import is here
        assert isinstance(self.service, Service_Module)
```

Of course, this may affect other usages of the imported symbols from that module into this file, so you may need to specify the import in more than one place.

Comment: I don't think you can do `import *` inside a function. When I try that, I get `SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level`.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Confirmed in Python 2.7 through 3.10.  I'm surprised the OP accepted the answer.  Of course, using `from service.service_module import *` was being lazy to save typing.  Using `from service.service_module import Service_Module` is allowed inside a function, and will delay the import, breaking the circular import issue as required.  Answer corrected.