# Why I can't call the object's class member in this case?

Tags: python-3.x

This code runs at the beginning

```
from Controller.DiscordClient import DiscordClient


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        DiscordClient.getInstance().run(DiscordClient.TOKEN)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

I have this DiscordClient class:

```
import discord
from Controller.Startup_Manager import *
from Controller.Message_Manager import *
from Controller.User_Message_Handler import *
from Controller.ReactionHandler import *


class DiscordClient(discord.Client):
    TOKEN = "token"
    __instance = None

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():
        """ Static access method. """
        if DiscordClient.__instance is None:
            DiscordClient()
        return DiscordClient.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        Startup_Manager.initiate_startup()
        """ Virtually private constructor. """
        if DiscordClient.__instance is not None:
            raise Exception("This class is a singleton!")
        else:
            DiscordClient.__instance = self
```

And the second class:

```
from .DiscordClient import DiscordClient
from Controller.POTD import *
from Controller.Task_Manager import *
from Model.RegexParseConstants import *
import re


class Startup_Manager:
    __TOO_MANY_REQUESTS_WAIT = 3 * 60
    __WAIT_TIME_UPDATE_VERSION_SECS = 45 * 60

    @staticmethod
    def initiate_startup():
        print(DiscordClient.TOKEN)
```

When I run this code and `initiate_startup()` gets called, it crashes, gives me this error:

```
name 'DiscordClient' is not defined
```

Edit: An update to the whole scenario. I don't know why the code crashes at DiscordClient despite this which called Startup_Manager in the first place.

Comment: are these two classes in the same file?

Comment: No, they aren't

Comment: did you properly import the file with `DiscordClient` in the file with `StartupManager`?

Comment: Yes, currently set as from Controller.DiscordClient import *

Comment: Sometimes Pycharm visual compiler tells me it's unresolved and usually it says it's not. Despite having the class imported.

Comment: it is not clear to me the structure of the program, could you maybe post the full contents of DiscordClient.py, also does this this import statement work for you? `from Controller.DiscordClient import DiscordClient`

Comment: No it crashed on it right away: ImportError: cannot import name 'DiscordClient'

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a `Controller.py` file in which you have the `DiscordClient`. so your import statement should be `from Controller import *` or specifically `from Controller import DiscordClient`

Comment: Unfortunately `from Controller import *` doesn't work. I also don't have a Controller.py, it's just the name of the directory.

Comment: @Newsonic please post the contents of the said files and the directory structure, it is not clear to me how your program is structured

Comment: @Newsonic the full contents please

Comment: Added the contents. Done.

Comment: I just noticed too any other static members calls work for all except DiscordClient in initiate_startup()

Comment: why are you using `from Controller.DiscordClient import DiscordClient` but later `from .DiscordClient import DiscordClient`? 
Also, some suggestions, when you ask for help, please post the directory structure (since this is an import related issue), your script files with the names and the full error traceback. and also do not use camel case for file names or module names in python since that is the convention for class names. i can't differentiate between the modules names and the class names since they are the same, please don't do that, this makes the code highly unreadable

Comment: You are right, that circular import alone was the problem, I guess there was no need to because it happened regardless of other files/structures. Sorry for the camel case problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the circular import, as suggested by @syfluqs. Delaying it to the last moment was the quick solution according to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50595843/